# Solving $b(5px - 3x) = a(qx - 4)$ for $x$, and stating any restrictions on the variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a high school student in Algebra II and while I normally have no trouble with problems dealing with algebraic equations, I simply cannot muster the answer to this question.

> Solve for $x$:
> $$b(5px - 3x) = a(qx - 4)$$
> State any restrictions on the variables.

I'll show you the process of deriving the solution that I have been taking, and if you could identify where I have been erroneous that would be greatly appreciated.

\begin{align*}
b(5px - 3x) &= a(qx - 4)\\
5bpx - 3bx &= aqx - 4a \\
5bpx &= aqx - 4a + 3bc \\
5bpx - aqx &= -4a + 3bc\\
x(5bp - aq) &= -4a + 3bc\\
x &=  \frac{-4a + 3bc}{5bp - aq}&&& (5bp ≠ aq)
\end{align*}

Comment: There is a missing special case, if $5bp-aq=-4a+3bc=0$ then any $x$ is a solution. This is, as in your comment, if we use $bc$ instead of $bx$.

Comment: If $5bp-aq=0$ and $-4a+3bc\not=0$, then there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the between the second and third lines, it looks like you just made a typo. You added $3bx$ to both sides, but then you wrote $3bc$ on the other side. The equation in the third line should have been

$$ 5bpx = aqx - 4a + 3bx$$

Comment: My mistake. The expression on the left was intended to be b(5px - 3c) with -3c as that term rather than -3x.